# Where are the keys?

Tags: hotline-miami-2

So, I´m on the 4th scene of chapter 1. And after I kill everyone the game tells me to "GET THE KEYS" And I can´t find them anywhere. Not sure what i´m doing wrong. Anyone already there?

Answer (score 4):

The key is dropped from the Swat unit. This is the guy with the baseball cap and the two magnums that require you to kill him with a finisher.

[image]

Once you kill all the cops in the room and it prompts you to find the key, the key will be located where the SWAT unit was.

If done correctly the objective in the lower left should now change to "Get Her"

[image]

Comment: Thanks, man! But yeah, the thing was that once I kill him, the key was in the wall and I could not see it. So, I just restart the stage and there it was.